# Replacing Model object by ViewModel object will raise an exception when trying to save a new record

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a model class named Server and I have created a new ServerToEdit viewModel class, but when I am trying to submit the viewModel I will get the following error on the repository.save() method.

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'TMS.Models.Server', but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'TMS.ViewModels.ServerToEdit'.

The viewModel class is :-

```
public class ServerToEdit
    {
        public Server Server { get; set; }
       [Required]
        public String IPAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

Part of the Create view is:-

```
model TMS.ViewModels.ServerToEdit

@* This partial view defines form fields that will appear when creating and editing entities *@
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Server.CustomerName)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.Server.CustomerName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.Server.CustomerName)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
   IP Address
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IPAddress)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IPAddress)
</div>


IPAddress
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model =>model.Server.ILOIP)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.Server.ILOIP)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.Server.ILOIP)
</div>
```

The Create actin method is :-

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(Server server, TechnologyIP technologyIP)
        {
           try 
           { 
               if (ModelState.IsValid) 
           {
                repository.InsertOrUpdateServer(server,technologyIP);
                repository.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
```

Finally the InsertOrUpdateServer repository method is:-

```
public void InsertOrUpdateServer(Server server, TechnologyIP technologyIP)
        {
            if (server.ServerID == default(int))
            {
                // New entity
                int technologyypeID = GetTechnologyTypeID("Server");
                Technology technology = new Technology
                {
                    IsDeleted = true,
                    TypeID = technologyypeID,
                    Tag = "S" + GetTagMaximumeNumber(technologyypeID).ToString()

                };

                InsertOrUpdateTechnology(technology);
                Save();



                var auditinfo = IntiateAudit(tms.AuditActions.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name.ToUpper() == "ADD").ActionID,
                    tms.TechnologyTypes.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name.ToUpper() == "Server").AssetTypeID,
                 "TDMGROUP\administrator", technology.TechnologyID);

                server.ServerID = technology.TechnologyID;
                technologyIP.TechnologyID = technology.TechnologyID;
                tms.Servers.Add(server);
                InsertOrUpdateTechnologyIP(technologyIP);
                technology.IsDeleted = false;
                InsertOrUpdateTechnology(technology);
                InsertOrUpdateAudit(auditinfo);
            }
            else
            {
                // Existing entity
                var auditinfo = IntiateAudit(tms.AuditActions.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name.ToUpper() == "EDIT").ActionID,
                    tms.TechnologyTypes.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name.ToUpper() == "Server").AssetTypeID,
                 "TDMGROUP\administrator", server.ServerID);
                tms.Entry(server).State = EntityState.Modified;
                tms.Entry(technologyIP).State = EntityState.Modified;
                InsertOrUpdateAudit(auditinfo);
            }
        }
```

thanks in advance for any help ?

Comment: Where does the TechnologyIP come from in your Action? It's neither in your ViewModel, nor in your View.

Comment: The TechnologyIP is just a table that stores @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IPAddress) and the TechnologyID.so i only need to get the @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IPAddress) from the view then insdide the repository method i will populte the TechnologyID for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, change your ViewModel to this:

```
public class ServerToEdit
{
    public Server Server { get; set; }
    public TechnologyIP TechnologyIP { get; set; }
}
```

And, change your Action to this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(ServerToEdit serverToEdit)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       try 
       { 
           repository.InsertOrUpdateServer(serverToEdit.Server, serverToEdit.TechnologyIP);
           repository.Save();
           return RedirectToAction("Index");
       }
       catch
       {
           // Some code... 
       }
   }
}
```

Then, in your View, you'll have:

```
@model TMS.ViewModels.ServerToEdit

@* This partial view defines form fields that will appear when creating and editing entities *@
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Server.CustomerName)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.Server.CustomerName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.Server.CustomerName)
</div>

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TechnologyIP.TechnologyID)
<div class="editor-label">
   IP Address
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TechnologyIP.IPAddress)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TechnologyIP.IPAddress)
</div>    

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model =>model.Server.ILOIP)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.Server.ILOIP)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.Server.ILOIP)
</div>
```

Comment: thanksa lot for your help, but what will be the difference ? i think the model binder should do this for me.

Comment: Why should the model binder bind a string value (IPAddress) to a TechnoloyIP object?

Comment: You also need a Hidden input for TechnologyID in your View. See the updated answer.

Comment: because it will check if the TechnologyIP.IPAddress and the field name on the view is the same or not. then it will map the IPAddress string to the IPAddress object property.? i though this will be the case ?